Is it proper grammar to always use “you three” instead of “the three of you”?
There is a show on TV with 3 contestants, and the host always says “you three” to them, and it doesn’t seem right. (Example: We will give you three another set of questions after the commercial break.) I think the host should be saying “the three of you”.  There are only three contestants during the entire episode, therefore, the three of you. If there were eight contestants and the host pointed out and said,“you three” will continue to the next round, and the rest of you will go home - that seems correct.  Using “you three” seems to indicate that they have picked 3 out of a group, whereas using “the three of you” indicates that they are the only ones there. Am I wrong about this?

Saying you three is  fine in the TV show example.  That phrase and the three of you mean the same and have the same usage whether there are three contestants or eight.  The choice is up to the speaker.
